# how to execute (exec) external system commands in Scala actor?

Tags: scala, actor

to run an external command, I should

```
import sys.process._
val result="ls a" !
```

then when use actor, I need to also use "!" to send message. So ! is defined both in actor and in process, but I need to use them both in the same code block, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the issue of `Process` and `ActorRef` both defining a method with the same name.

An analog example would be

```
class A { def ! = println("A") }
class B { def ! = println("B") }
val a = new A
val b = new B
a.! // "A"
b.! // "B"
```

There's no name collision or ambiguity at all.

The only thing you have to worry about is the implicit conversion from `String` to `Process`.

`"foo".!` works because `Process` is the only class in which `String` can implicitly be converted to that defines a `!` method.

As the documentation says, if you instead use something like `"foo".lines`, then the compiler gets confuse because it doesn't know whether to convert `String` to `Process` or to `StringLike`, since both define a `lines` method.

But - again - this is not your case, and you can safely do something like:

```
"ls".!
sender ! "a message"
```

and the compiler should not complain.

Answer (score -1):

The [recommended](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder) approach for such cases seems to be import Process object only:

```
import scala.sys.process.Process
Process("find src -name *.scala -exec grep null {} ;") #| Process("xargs test -z") #&& Process("echo null-free") #|| Process("echo null detected") !
```

in your case:

```
import scala.sys.process.Process
Process("ls a")
```

Comment: that's a different matter: the docs suggests that approach in case you use a method on `String` that can make the implicit conversion ambiguous (like the deprecated `lines`, which is available on both `Process` and `StringLike`). It doesn't have anything to do with this case.

Comment: It does, because it allows you not to use ! for performing system commands. The other method would be aliasing '!' somehow.

Comment: no, it doesn't. The only possible issue is if the method leads to ambiguous implicit conversions, but in that case you get a specific compile-time error. There's such thing as method "aliasing".