# Why need a blank line after process(aString)! in scala?

Tags: scala

When I run an external process, looks like we need to add a blank line after the calling. Why it throws that error?

```
 class JobActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg:String =>
       Process(msg)!
                       // here need a blank line, otherwise it throws error 
       sender ! "complete"
  } 
}
```

the error is

```
[error]  found   : akka.actor.ActorRef
[error]  required: scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger
[error]        sender ! "complete"
[error]        ^
[error] one error found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You hit the exact reason of why postfix operators is a feature that generates a warning when you compile with the `-feature` flag.

Here's an extract that explains why such feature is still under discussion (emphasis added):

> postfixOps. Only where enabled, postfix operator notation  (expr op) 
>   will be allowed. *Why keep the feature?* Several DSLs written in Scala
>   need the notation. *Why control it?* **Postfix operators interact poorly
>   with semicolon inference**. Most programmers avoid them for this reason.

([source](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nlkvpoIRkx7at1qJEZafJwthZ3GeIklTFhqmXMvTX9Q/edit#))

`Process` defines two methods

```
abstract def !: Int 
abstract def !(log: ProcessLogger): Int
```

When you do

```
Process(msg)!
```

you mean to call the former, but since there's no unambiguous indication that the line should end (i.e. that a semicolon should be inferred), the parser starts reading the next line, it finds something can can syntactically be an argument (`sender`) and you end up calling the second version of `!` instead.

The resulting code is actually:

```
Process(msg)! sender ! "complete"
```

i.e.

```
(Process(msg).!(sender)).!("complete")
```

hence the error: `sender` is not an instance of `ProcessLogger`.

In order to fix it, you have to untangle the ambiguity yourself. There's many ways of doing it, the simplest one being to avoid the postfix operator altogether:

```
Process(msg).!
sender ! "complete"
```

Actually, given [this other question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339624/how-to-execute-exec-external-system-commands-in-scala-actor), you can even just do

```
msg.!
sender ! "complete"
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be another case where Scala's grammar does not allow for postfix operators in any other place than the end of an expression.

The first one was described in "[Why does this code need an empty line or a semicolon?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3739582/6309)"

Adding a semi-colon might also make the code compile, because of the [semicolon inference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2248353/6309).

```
Process(msg)!;
sender ! "complete"
```